# UITextView scrollRangeToVisible make range visible appear at the top

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am currently using UITextView. When I use scrollRangeToVisible it works but it brings the range to the bottom of the screen. How can I bring this range to the top of the screen. TLDR: UITextview method scrollRangeToVisible brings the characters of interest to bottom of view. I want it to come to top of view. How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Can you share a photo?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to:

- find the bounding box of the range you want at the top
- if it's below the current top line, add the height of the text view
- then call `.scrollRectToVisible()`

You also need some error and bounds checking. I put together an extension you can try out if you wish: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/19daac863553c51725a56f0bc3296076

Comment: Thanks for your help!